# Clang: Missing symbols but it exists in .dylib file

Tags: c++, clang

Minimal file

```cpp
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main() {
        glfwInit();
        return 0;
}
```

clang command

```
clang++ test.cpp -I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib
```

Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in test-69fe96.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

But as I checked, the symbol seems to exist

```
nm /opt/homebrew/lib/libglfw.dylib | grep _glfwInit
```

output

```
0000000000010e68 t __glfwInitEGL
(omit lines)
0000000000006244 T _glfwInit
0000000000006450 T _glfwInitHint
```

The symbol exists and I have included this file in clang command. I don't know why it is missing.

Comment: Your compile/link command appears to be missing `-lglfw`.

Comment: `-L` tells *where* the libs are, but not that it should be linked. That's option `-l`. You usually need both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the library itself to the command:

```
clang++ test.cpp -I/opt/homebrew/include \
-L/opt/homebrew/lib -lglfw
```